# EF in Database project in VS 2013

Tags: c#

I created SQL Server Database project in VS 2013. Is it possible to create Entity Framework for that project? I don't have option to insert EF in that project!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can download the extensions: 
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8363
or
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762

After the installation, you can find the option to create the Entity Framework model, in the 'Data' section when you add a new element for you project.

Comment: I installed but I still don't have option for EF for SQL Server Database project.

Comment: Create a new project (MVC4 or MVC5, etc). after create the project, right click in your project (Solution explorer) Add new Item >> Data >> Ado.net Entity Model

Comment: So you mean that isn't possible to add EF to DB project?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is called Database first.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj206878.aspx

**UPDATE:** I see your point now. Sadly, I haven't heard of any plugin that would generate the EF classes directly from the sql scripts located in your database project. The process you think of needs to parse all the scripts, so it's a more complicated one. You should try those plugins mentioned by the others!

Comment: Yes I want DB first. I know for that article, but I can't add EF to DB project. I don't have that option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [EF tools for Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=40762).

Or use [NuGet add the necessary EF binaries](https://www.nuget.org/packages/entityframework) to your project.

Comment: Where I have to instal EF? SQL Server Database project doesn't support that option. On VS I have already installed EF from nugget.